# Proof of generalized open & closed Newton-Cotes formulas

Tags: integration, reference-request, numerical-methods, quadrature

I am looking for proof of generalized open & closed Newton-Cotes formulas. I couldn't find any reference which properly proves both theorems. Most books just state the theorem and do not provide any proof.

Suppose that $\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i} f\left(x_{i}\right)$ denotes the $(n+1)$ -point open Newton-Cotes formula with $x_{-1}=a, x_{n+1}=b,$ and $h=(b-a) /(n+2) .$ There exists $\xi \in(a, b)$ for which
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i} f\left(x_{i}\right)+\frac{h^{n+3} f^{(n+2)}(\xi)}{(n+2) !} \int_{-1}^{n+1} t^{2}(t-1) \cdots(t-n) d t
$$
if $n$ is even and $f \in C^{n+2}[a, b],$ and
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) d x=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i} f\left(x_{i}\right)+\frac{h^{n+2} f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1) !} \int_{-1}^{n+1} t(t-1) \cdots(t-n) d t
$$
$
\text { if } n \text { is odd and } f \in C^{n+1}[a, b] \text { . }
$

Answer (score 0):

You can find the proof in "[Isaacson, E. and Keller. Analysis of Numerical Methods](https://archive.org/details/analysisofnumeri00isaa/page/300/mode/2up)" chapter 7.

**NOTE:** To preview the book, one must have to borrow the book and to do that one must have an login account on [Archive](http://archive.org). You can [create a for account for free](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj20sDb9aHuAhWm4XMBHR4DBDYQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Farchive.org%2Faccount%2Fsignup&usg=AOvVaw19u8P0zoGFyiIfHu2ZtHR2).

Comment: My question is not answered in that book. No proof has been provided.

Comment: @ FreeMind. In the version of 1994 of this book, you can find the proof in page 310 for the even case and in page 311-312 for the odd case. The authors prove the theorems before state it.

Comment: @HiterDean thanks for the information